# Yarn install not working after updating node

Tags: react-native, npm, yarnpkg

I'm sorry that this is a very vague question, but I find it difficult with dependency management as sometimes when I get errors, I haven't a clue where to start looking to fix the problem.

I would be very grateful, for any direction or help to show how to fix the problem, and get yarn working again so that I can install packages.

Ultimately, I'm looking to install facebook ads for expo, but keep getting an error when I try to do `yarn install`

Thanks very much

Here is the error readout from my terminal.

```
`yarn install v1.13.0
[1/4]   Resolving packages...
[2/4]   Fetching packages...
info @expo/traveling-fastlane-linux@1.9.11: The platform "darwin" is incompatible with this module.
info "@expo/traveling-fastlane-linux@1.9.11" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
warning multiyargs@1.0.0: The engine "yargs" appears to be invalid.
info @expo/ngrok-bin-darwin-ia32@2.2.8: The CPU architecture "x64" is incompatible with this module.
info "@expo/ngrok-bin-darwin-ia32@2.2.8" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
info @expo/ngrok-bin-freebsd-ia32@2.2.8: The platform "darwin" is incompatible with this module.
info "@expo/ngrok-bin-freebsd-ia32@2.2.8" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
info @expo/ngrok-bin-freebsd-ia32@2.2.8: The CPU architecture "x64" is incompatible with this module.
info @expo/ngrok-bin-freebsd-x64@2.2.8: The platform "darwin" is incompatible with this module.
info "@expo/ngrok-bin-freebsd-x64@2.2.8" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
info @expo/ngrok-bin-linux-arm@2.2.8: The platform "darwin" is incompatible with this module.
info "@expo/ngrok-bin-linux-arm@2.2.8" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
info @expo/ngrok-bin-linux-arm@2.2.8: The CPU architecture "x64" is incompatible with this module.
info @expo/ngrok-bin-linux-arm64@2.2.8: The platform "darwin" is incompatible with this module.
info "@expo/ngrok-bin-linux-arm64@2.2.8" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
info @expo/ngrok-bin-linux-arm64@2.2.8: The CPU architecture "x64" is incompatible with this module.
info @expo/ngrok-bin-linux-ia32@2.2.8: The platform "darwin" is incompatible with this module.
info "@expo/ngrok-bin-linux-ia32@2.2.8" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
info @expo/ngrok-bin-linux-ia32@2.2.8: The CPU architecture "x64" is incompatible with this module.
info @expo/ngrok-bin-linux-x64@2.2.8: The platform "darwin" is incompatible with this module.
info "@expo/ngrok-bin-linux-x64@2.2.8" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
info @expo/ngrok-bin-sunos-x64@2.2.8: The platform "darwin" is incompatible with this module.
info "@expo/ngrok-bin-sunos-x64@2.2.8" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
info @expo/ngrok-bin-win32-ia32@2.2.8-beta.1: The platform "darwin" is incompatible with this module.
info "@expo/ngrok-bin-win32-ia32@2.2.8-beta.1" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
info @expo/ngrok-bin-win32-ia32@2.2.8-beta.1: The CPU architecture "x64" is incompatible with this module.
info @expo/ngrok-bin-win32-x64@2.2.8-beta.1: The platform "darwin" is incompatible with this module.
info "@expo/ngrok-bin-win32-x64@2.2.8-beta.1" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
[3/4]   Linking dependencies...
warning " > @expo/vector-icons@9.0.0" has unmet peer dependency "expo-font@^2.0.0".
warning " > @react-navigation/web@1.0.0-alpha.9" has unmet peer dependency "@react-navigation/core@^3.0.0-alpha.13".
warning "babel-preset-expo > @babel/plugin-proposal-decorators@7.3.0" has unmet peer dependency "@babel/core@^7.0.0-0".
warning "babel-preset-expo > metro-react-native-babel-preset > @babel/plugin-transform-arrow-functions@7.2.0" has unmet peer dependency "@babel/core@^7.0.0-0".
warning "babel-preset-expo > metro-react-native-babel-preset > @babel/plugin-transform-computed-properties@7.2.0" has unmet peer dependency "@babel/core@^7.0.0-0".
warning "babel-preset-expo > metro-react-native-babel-preset > @babel/plugin-transform-exponentiation-operator@7.2.0" has unmet peer dependency "@babel/core@^7.0.0-0".
warning "babel-preset-expo > metro-react-native-babel-preset > @babel/plugin-transform-literals@7.2.0" has unmet peer dependency "@babel/core@^7.0.0-0".
warning "babel-preset-expo > metro-react-native-babel-preset > @babel/plugin-transform-shorthand-properties@7.2.0" has unmet peer dependency "@babel/core@^7.0.0-0".
warning "babel-preset-expo > metro-react-native-babel-preset > @babel/plugin-transform-spread@7.2.2" has unmet peer dependency "@babel/core@^7.0.0-0".
warning "babel-preset-expo > metro-react-native-babel-preset > @babel/plugin-transform-sticky-regex@7.2.0" has unmet peer dependency "@babel/core@^7.0.0-0".
warning "babel-preset-expo > metro-react-native-babel-preset > @babel/plugin-proposal-export-default-from@7.2.0" has unmet peer dependency "@babel/core@^7.0.0-0".
warning "babel-preset-expo > metro-react-native-babel-preset > @babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import@7.2.0" has unmet peer dependency "@babel/core@^7.0.0-0".
warning "babel-preset-expo > metro-react-native-babel-preset > @babel/plugin-syntax-export-default-from@7.2.0" has unmet peer dependency "@babel/core@^7.0.0-0".
warning "babel-preset-expo > metro-react-native-babel-preset > @babel/plugin-transform-block-scoping@7.2.0" has unmet peer dependency "@babel/core@^7.0.0-0".
warning "babel-preset-expo > metro-react-native-babel-preset > @babel/plugin-transform-classes@7.2.2" has unmet peer dependency "@babel/core@^7.0.0-0".
warning "babel-preset-expo > metro-react-native-babel-preset > @babel/plugin-transform-destructuring@7.2.0" has unmet peer dependency "@babel/core@^7.0.0-0".
warning "babel-preset-expo > metro-react-native-babel-preset > @babel/plugin-transform-for-of@7.2.0" has unmet peer dependency "@babel/core@^7.0.0-0".
warning "babel-preset-expo > metro-react-native-babel-preset > @babel/plugin-transform-function-name@7.2.0" has unmet peer dependency "@babel/core@^7.0.0-0".
warning "babel-preset-expo > metro-react-native-babel-preset > @babel/plugin-transform-object-assign@7.2.0" has unmet peer dependency "@babel/core@^7.0.0-0".
warning "babel-preset-expo > metro-react-native-babel-preset > @babel/plugin-transform-parameters@7.2.0" has unmet peer dependency "@babel/core@^7.0.0-0".
warning "babel-preset-expo > metro-react-native-babel-preset > @babel/plugin-transform-react-display-name@7.2.0" has unmet peer dependency "@babel/core@^7.0.0-0".
warning "babel-preset-expo > metro-react-native-babel-preset > @babel/plugin-transform-react-jsx@7.3.0" has unmet peer dependency "@babel/core@^7.0.0-0".
warning "babel-preset-expo > metro-react-native-babel-preset > @babel/plugin-transform-react-jsx-source@7.2.0" has unmet peer dependency "@babel/core@^7.0.0-0".
warning "babel-preset-expo > metro-react-native-babel-preset > @babel/plugin-transform-regenerator@7.0.0" has unmet peer dependency "@babel/core@^7.0.0-0".
warning "babel-preset-expo > metro-react-native-babel-preset > @babel/plugin-transform-runtime@7.2.0" has unmet peer dependency "@babel/core@^7.0.0-0".
warning "babel-preset-expo > metro-react-native-babel-preset > @babel/plugin-transform-template-literals@7.2.0" has unmet peer dependency "@babel/core@^7.0.0-0".
warning "babel-preset-expo > metro-react-native-babel-preset > @babel/plugin-transform-typescript@7.2.0" has unmet peer dependency "@babel/core@^7.0.0-0".
warning "babel-preset-expo > metro-react-native-babel-preset > @babel/plugin-transform-unicode-regex@7.2.0" has unmet peer dependency "@babel/core@^7.0.0-0".
warning "firebase > @firebase/database@0.3.11" has unmet peer dependency "@firebase/app-types@0.x".
warning "firebase > @firebase/firestore@1.0.1" has unmet peer dependency "@firebase/app-types@0.x".
warning "firebase > @firebase/functions@0.3.6" has unmet peer dependency "@firebase/app-types@0.x".
warning "firebase > @firebase/messaging@0.3.10" has unmet peer dependency "@firebase/app-types@0.x".
warning "firebase > @firebase/storage@0.2.7" has unmet peer dependency "@firebase/app-types@0.x".
warning "firebase > @firebase/auth > @firebase/auth-types@0.5.1" has unmet peer dependency "@firebase/app-types@0.x".
warning "firebase > @firebase/auth > @firebase/auth-types@0.5.1" has unmet peer dependency "@firebase/util@0.x".
warning "firebase > @firebase/database > @firebase/database-types@0.3.4" has unmet peer dependency "@firebase/app-types@0.x".
warning "firebase > @firebase/firestore > @firebase/firestore-types@1.0.1" has unmet peer dependency "@firebase/app-types@0.x".
warning "firebase > @firebase/functions > @firebase/messaging-types@0.2.4" has unmet peer dependency "@firebase/app-types@0.x".
warning "firebase > @firebase/storage > @firebase/storage-types@0.2.4" has unmet peer dependency "@firebase/app-types@0.x".
warning "firebase > @firebase/storage > @firebase/storage-types@0.2.4" has unmet peer dependency "@firebase/util@0.x".
warning "geofirestore > @firebase/firestore-types@0.8.0" has unmet peer dependency "@firebase/app-types@0.x".
warning "react-native > metro-react-native-babel-transformer@0.51.0" has unmet peer dependency "@babel/core@*".
warning "react-native > @react-native-community/cli > metro-react-native-babel-transformer@0.51.1" has unmet peer dependency "@babel/core@*".
warning " > react-native-sectioned-multi-select@0.7.1" has unmet peer dependency "prop-types@^15.6.0".
warning " > react-native-sectioned-multi-select@0.7.1" has unmet peer dependency "react-native-vector-icons@^4.1.1".
warning "react-navigation > react-navigation-drawer@1.2.1" has unmet peer dependency "react-native-screens@^1.0.0 || ^1.0.0-alpha".
warning "react-navigation > react-navigation-stack@1.4.0" has unmet peer dependency "react-native-screens@^1.0.0 || ^1.0.0-alpha".
warning "react-navigation > react-navigation-tabs@1.1.4" has unmet peer dependency "react-native-screens@^1.0.0 || ^1.0.0-alpha".
warning "babel-preset-expo > metro-react-native-babel-preset@0.49.2" has unmet peer dependency "@babel/core@*".
[4/4]   Building fresh packages...
[-/10] ⠂ waiting...
[6/10] ⠂ grpc
[-/10] ⠂ waiting...
[8/10] ⠂ grpc
error /../node_modules/grpc: Command failed.
Exit code: 1
Command: node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build --library=static_library
Arguments: 
Directory: /../node_modules/grpc`
```

Comment: Could you try remove yarn.lock and package-lock???

Comment: Thanks for your answer but no it didn't work

Comment: um..Could you try upgrade Yarn?? `brew upgrade yarn`

Comment: No, that didn't work either. Not sure what I've done to it to break it